# password field showing hashed value on form value update

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True))
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

I have views.py to show the form instance and update the instance.

On edit the form data,all other field are showing the correct value,password field is showing the entire hashed value from database and not the entered password.

I don't know how to show the entered password instead of hashed value in database.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, of course. It's hashed for a reason, which is to make it impossible to get the clear text value.

You must have noticed though that no website or application will ever show you your current password when you're updating: you usually have to enter it yourself for verification, then enter the new password twice.

Comment: My client is requesting to do that function.I want to implement it in my application.May i know how to implement this.Currently it is showing the hashed value and if i save that,the original password get disappeared.

Comment: Your client is asking for something that can't - and shouldn't - be done, and you as a developer should know better. There's no point asking "may I know how to implement this", there is no way.

Comment: Yes @DanielRoseman is absolutely, right. You need to convince your client. Tell them the dark side of it. I am sure they will drop this requirement.

Comment: @user2681579: There are two types of encryption: one-way encryption and two-way encryption. Django follows one way encryption(sha1). So once the password is encrypted it can't be decrypted. If you really wanna do this(which is really a foolish thing to do), you should change the Django password hashing mechanism or use your own User model and store the password in plain text(or follow two-way encryption)

Comment: Never ever store passwords in plain text, there is no comfort on earth that would justify the hassle you will have once the passwords leak...

Answer (score 0):

Remember about security.

```
#app/hashers.py

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import BasePasswordHasher
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict

class DummyPasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "dummy"

    def encode(self, password, salt):
        return "dummy$%s" % (password)

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        algorithm, hash = encoded.split('$', 2)
        return hash == password

    def safe_summary(self, encoded):
        algorithm, hash = encoded.split('$', 2)
        return SortedDict([
            ('algorithm', algorithm),
            ('password', hash),
        ])

#settings.py

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'app.hashers.DummyPasswordHasher',
)

PREFERRED_HASHER = 'app.hashers.DummyPasswordHasher'
```

**EDIT** I've corrected spelling mistakes

Comment: The above answer i tried,but it is not making any changes in my application.The `hashers.py` is not imported i think because after i executed the application the `hashers.pyc` file is not created. Wheather this save the password in plain text.Need more explanation

Comment: My code contains some mistakes. It is not working still. Sorry

Comment: So? I've checked it and the database is keeping pure passwords without hashing. What about yours?

Comment: The thing is that after replacing PASSWORD_HASHERS you need to delete your user accounts from db. I recommend you to syncdb once again. Comipled files with `pyc` extension are made with your `wsgi` server and don't correspond with the topic

Comment: I tried with new db,after including the hashers.py i did syncdb and db migration,created superuser then noticed that application is using the old hashing algorithm.Even after syncdb,hashers.py are not compiled.Do i need to comment the password hashing code.